# The textview is empty when I use substring

Tags: android, string, substring

I am doing an application in android. The application saves a quote or an expression in a textfield. The user has the opportunity to change this text. But I wanted that when the quote is appeared in the `TextView`, it is not appeared at all. I wanted only the first 5 characters of the quote to be appeared. I try to do this using the substring, but when I open the `TextView` nothing appears. The `TextView` is empty. What can I do?

Can anyone help me , please.

Thanks in advance.

This is the line where I use substring:

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( Quote.this,quoteList, R.layout.quote_entry, new String[] { "quoteId", "textQuote".substring(0, 4)}, new int[] {R.id.quoteId, R.id.textQuote});
```

And here is the entire class

```
package com.example.prova1;

/**This class is the page of quotes*/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import com.example.prova1.Database;
import com.example.prova1.EditQuote;
import com.example.prova1.AddQuote;
import com.example.prova1.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Quote extends ListActivity {

 Intent intent;
 TextView quoteId;

 Database quotedatabase = new Database(this);

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.quote_main);//define that the interface used is quote_main

  //Store data from database in an array list

  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> quoteList =  quotedatabase.getAllItems();

  //Check if there are quotes to display
  if(quoteList.size()!=0) {

   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {


     quoteId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quoteId);

     String itemIdValue = quoteId.getText().toString(); 

     Intent  theIndent = new Intent(getApplication(),ShowQuote.class);


     theIndent.putExtra("quoteId", itemIdValue); 

     finish();

     startActivity(theIndent); 

         }
   }); 

   // Here we use ListAdapter as a bridge between ListView and the data of ListView

   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
          Quote.this,quoteList,
          R.layout.quote_entry,
          new String[] {
                       "quoteId",
                       "textQuote".substring(0, 4)
                        },
             new int[] {
                       R.id.quoteId,
                       R.id.textQuote}
                    );

   setListAdapter(adapter);


  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can Anyone help me with this task?

Comment: Why do the substring on a String literal?  Why not just code the String you want: "text"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the SDK installed at the moment to test your code, but I do have a couple suggestions.

First: Try the code without the substring, and see if that works.
Second: If that works, then move the substring operation to the line before and pass in the result to the SimpleAdapter.

I say this because I have the feeling that the substring is not actually your problem. And this is just a good way to test that.

I'd also check your layout "R.layout.quote_entry" and make sure there isn't anything weird going on with that. Such as you having "R.id.textQuote" actually being 'gone' and another TextView being visibly shown, etc. I had this problem once. I had two EditText fields, and only one of them was being shown, so the Activity looked right, but wasn't behaving properly.

Comment: The code works fine without the substring. Even if I  move the substring operation in the line before, it does not work. I checked R.layout.quote_entry and everything is OK with that.

Comment: So do you have any other idea?

Comment: Yeah, actually, Pull the String[] creation outside the declartion of the SimpleAdapter then, It looks like there is an issue with creating the anonymous String[] and the substring(), I'm not sure 'why' that is offhand, but I'm thinking that it has to do with how String as immutable. So therefore the Substring() of the string is trying to change the value of the string in the array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html